# make UIGestureRecognizer respond to a gesture that is already in progress and being recognized by another recognizer

Tags: uiscrollview, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

So here's the deal:

1. I have a view with a collection view (subview) whose content is
   taller than its bounds' height. So the collection view will allow
   vertical scrolling to see all its items.
2. Also, this collection view is positioned aprox. half its height past the bottom of its superview (the vc main view). That is, half the collection view is "hidden" past the bottom of the screen.
3. I'm using UIKit Dynamics to allow to drag the collection view up and down. It's rest position is as explained in 2. It's "expanded" position is all the way up up to the vc's navigation bar.

To trigger the dynamics, I have a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached to the main vc view (superview of the collection view) and if it detects that a drag is started where the collection view is, it starts the dynamics process to pull it up or down.

The behavior I'm trying to achieve, however is that:

1. If the collection view is collapsed (bottom), dragging should pull it up via dynamics but not allow the collection view's pan recognizer to make it scroll at the same time.
2. Once I reach my target height in terms of pulling the collection view up, the collection view should start responding to my gesture also, scrolling in the vertical direction inside the collection view. This switch to the collection view also responding to gestures needs to be continuous. That is, if I set the collection view's `scrollEnabled` depending on its position in the superview this does not work: the gesture is already in process so the collection view won't start scrolling until I end the current gesture and start a new one.

So is there a way to make the gesture recognizer in the collection view aware that a gesture is in progress and have it start recognizing that gesture even though it is already being handled by the superview recognizer?

**UPDATE:**

At this point I'll even settle for a solution with two nested scrollviews.
If anyone is interested, I made a little project with an attempt. It's still far from acceptable.
Here are the main issues with the nested scrollview approach:

1. By default, the problem of a scrollview (and subclasses) not responding to gestures that are in progress by the time `scrollEnabled` is set to YES holds, regardless of dealing with 2 scroll views or a gesture recognizer and a scrollview.
2. I solved this by subclassing the classes in question (in my example, one table view and one scrollview) and manipulating the `scrollEnabled`property along with `-setContentOffset:` and setting the view's recognizers to recognize simultaneously. At this point, I can finally set scrollviews (or subclasses for that matter) `scrollEnabled` arbitrarily and get them to respond to gestures in progress.

But then I'm faced with a few other problems:

1. depending on whether the gesture has been going on for a while before I set a view's `scrollEnabled` to YES, the view starts getting messages to set its content offset to values that are not right. That is, if the tableview scrolling is disabled until the parent scrollview reaches its maximum content offset, then turning the tableview on to respond to the gesture while the gesture is still in progress causes it to try and scroll to the parent view's contentOffset instead of the next step value from 0 (since its content offset is really at 0 until this point).
2. Depending on whether the gesture is a continuous pan up past the parent scrollview's maximum offset and then down back again or, instead 2 discrete swipes (one up, one down) I also get different offset results.
3. when pulling the tableview down to the point where its content offset should be <= 0 and enable scrolling again in the parent view, the tableview doesn't always end up perfectly aligned to its content offset of 0, even if I round the value to 0.

[sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqpjrcgtwbjv7ix/fsd.zip)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to implement the `-gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` method of your `UIPanGestureRecognizer`'s `delegate` to return `YES` when the gesture recogniser passed is your `UICollectionView`'s `panGestureRecognizer`.

Then, initially set your `UICollectionView`'s `scrollEnabled` to `NO`. Once your `UICollectionView` is at its target height (according to the movement brought about by your `UIPanGestureRecognizer`), set your `UICollectionView`'s `scrollEnabled` to `YES` and begin ignoring events from your own `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Alternatively, you could put your `UICollectionView` into a parent `UIScrollView` to achieve similar results.

Comment: I previously tried a setup exactly like the one you mention with simultaneous recognition but the scrollview would not start responding to gestures until I ended the ongoing one being recognized by the pan recognizer. They key difference might be that you say I should thereafter ignore gestures in my own recognizer. How do I ignore gestures? Or what do you mean by "begin ignoring events from your own UIPanGestureRecognizer." ?

Comment: If the scrollview didn't start responding to gestures until your own pan gesture recogniser stopped, it sounds like you didn't have simultaneous recognition set up correctly. By "ignore" I mean just don't do anything with the callbacks you get. You'll still get them, and so will the scrollview's gesture recogniser, if things are set up correctly.

Comment: Again, though: try just using embedded scrollviews if you can?

Comment: I've tried also embedded scrollviews and no go, because the child scrollview (on top of the parent) will always intercept the touches first and not pass them thru to the parent. I also tried subclassing UIScrollView to 1 - set `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneously...` to YES so it passes touches to the superview and also overrode `-setContentOffset` so it doesn't scroll until the parent sets `-scrollEnabled` back to YES. And this works but for the fact that when the scroll view decelerates to the last offset, the last offset makes it jump to a slightly off position.

Comment: btw, I don't know how could I possibly set up simultaneous recognition wrong: it's basically returning YES from a method. My point is, that if you 1 - set scrollEnabled = NO in some view that tracks gestures, 2 - start a gesture that another recognizer starts tracking and 3 - at some arbitrary point DURING the gesture (UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) switch the first view scrollEnabled = YES, the view's recognizer will not pick up the gesture in progress. Or at least, UISCrollView does something else by which once a gesture is in progress it prevents its recognizer from tracking it again.